Getting Vue draggable is not defined error in mobile browser
Using vue3 draggable - working fine in laptop browser but where as in mobile browser, getting vue draggable is not defined error.
const mainSortBundleApp = createApp(sortBundleApp);
mainSortBundleApp.component('draggable', vuedraggable);
mainSortBundleApp.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve';
mainSortBundleApp.mount('#vueSortableApp');

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.10.2/Sortable.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuedraggable@4.1.0/dist/vuedraggable.umd.min.js">

Is it possible to give condition check whether to register the vuedraggable component or not?

What is the mobile browser? Otherwise yes, dynamic imports is a thing if you want to conditional import your package. Otherwise, why do you load the UMD version of Vuedraggable and not the ESM one?

I did try various ways but noting worked. Can you provide me with any other option which I could try. Using safari mobile browser. It is not nessary for the draggable to work in mobile but atleast it has to load the contents in the page but it is not as it is failing in the first step itself( vuedraggable not defined)
